# Compare in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a bunch of data in a database that i want to write a search function for. The problem is that i'm getting many duplicates.
The data is structured in Names and Surnames and i want to only send one unique of both so if i have two people with the first name Foo, and surname Bar only one will show.

No matter how I think of it I always come back to that I need to compare them.

```
var names = db.People
      .Where(r => r.Name.Contains(q))
      .OrderBy(r=> r.Name)
       *Psuedo-Code*
       if((this.Name==next.Name)&&(this.surSame==next.Surname)
           toss next data and loop to next
       *Psuedo-Code*
      .Take(5);
```

Maybe a bit messy, but you get the idea what I want to achieve. Can I do this in some way or is there any better way to go about it?

Comment: Sounds like `.Distinct` might work for your purposes.

Comment: yeah, i have tried it but did not get my head around how to use it for this purpose. If i go distinct on the Name or Surname i will only get one.

Comment: What is `db`? Or: is this linq to sql?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do this:

```
var names = db.People
    .Where(r => r.Name.Contains(q))
    .Select(r => new { Name = r.Name, Surname = r.Surname })
    .Distinct()
    .Take(5);
```

But if that won't work because you need the whole People record, you just want the first, I've done something like this with success:

```
var names = db.People
   .Where(r => r.Name.Contains(q))
   .GroupBy(r => new { Name = r.Name, Surname = r.Surname })
   .Select(g => g.First())
   .Take(5);
```

Comment: It looks like you had the same answer as me, 1 minute faster. The `new { Name = r.Name, Surname = r.Surname }` anonymous type declaration can actually be replaced with the shorter but equivalent `new { r.Name, r.Surname }` if you like.

Comment: Thanks! I was about to throw my laptop out the window. The only change i had to do was to to use "FirstorDefault" instead of first due to other functions. Again, big thanks. It made my day! :)

Answer (score 4):

`Distinct` utilizing `Equals` on `People` class would be the correct way, but here's an alternative that is more "inline":

```
var names = db.People
  .Where(r => r.Name.Contains(q))
  .GroupBy(r => new { r.Name, r.Surname })
  .Select(g => g.First())
  .OrderBy(r => r.Name)
  .Take(5);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Distinct()` and implement the method `Equals` in `People` class, or use an auxiliary class to compare them:

```
public class PeopleComparer : IEqualityComparer<People>
{
    public bool Equals(People x, People y)
    {
        return x.Name == y.Name && x.Surname == y.Surname;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(People obj)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return (obj.Name.GetHashCode() * 31) + obj.Surname.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You would also need a sensible `GetHashCode` implementation.

Comment: Yes, I think it's better to delegate the `GetHashCode` calculation to `People` class as it is now.

Comment: No, actually, not at all.  In fact doing so breaks the implementation.  It's *essential* that the hash code and equality be based on the same "thing".  The hash code should be based on the name and surname, just like the equality.

Comment: Ok, I thought you meant to move the code to the `People` class, because if he implements the `Equals`, the `GetHashCode` calculation should be the same. So then the first version is good enough, since it uses a prime number to multiply the first hash code.

Comment: You would also want to wrap the body of `GetHashCode` with `unchecked { ... }`.

Comment: I haven't thought about that since it is a very short expression - you need a really long name (much more than 10K characters) to cause an overflow. I'll edit the answer to improve it anyway.